# Access data within tupples

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tupples like so:

```
     tupples=[(41, 'Mike'), (29, 'Tom'), (28, 'Sarah'), (22, 'Jane'), (18, 'John']
```

The ints are ages of the individuals and the strings are their names. The tupples are ordered by the individials age on purpose.

I understand list indexes work here. So if I want to access the first tupple then:

```
  tupples[0]
```

will access

```
 (41, 'Mike')
```

How do I access the values within the tupples?

I would like to loop through the tupple and print:
    "They are" AGE "years old, and their name is" NAME.

So for tupples[0] it would look like:

```
 "They are" 41 "years old, and their name is" Mike.
```

Comment: Actually you should write `tupples[0]` to access the first element...

Comment: You index tuple objects the exact same way as lists

Comment: Youre right, tupples[0] for the first instance - That was a mistake, my apologies. I'll change that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess
`tupples[1][0]`
would work just fine.

Edit:
If you want both age and name as variables, do something like this:

```
age, name = tupples[0]
```

Comment: I did not know about this approach, thank you I will try this

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) like:

```
data = [(41, 'Mike'), (29, 'Tom'), (28, 'Sarah'),
        (22, 'Jane'), (18, 'John')]

for age, name in data:
    print("They are {} years old, and their name is {}.".format(age, name))
```

Or you can access the elements in the tuple as `[0]` and `[1]` like:

```
for datum in data:
    print("They are {} years old, and their name is {}.".format(datum[0], datum[1]))
```

Or you can use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) like:

```
for datum in data:
    print("They are {} years old, and their name is {}.".format(*datum))
```